# I want to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} B_n/A_n = B/A$ where $B_n$ and $A_n$ are 2 sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

$A_n$ and $B_n$ are sequences. I know how to prove that  $\lim_{n\to \infty}  A_n+B_n = A+B$

I struggle with this problem though. Do I have to prove that $1/A_n = 1/A$ therefore $\lim B_n/A_n = \lim B_n * \lim 1/A_n$

and then prove seperately that $\lim B_n = B$ and $\lim 1/A_n = 1/A$ ? Or do it another way?

I get lost on proving $\lim_{n\to \infty}  B_n/A_n = B/A$ and also am not sure if that is the correct approach. Is there a simpler way where I use some properties of limits?

P.S. Thanks to the person who edited this lo look properly!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4Lpq.png)

Comment: How about dividing by the greatest values in each sequence?

Comment: It is a nice theorem that says if you are taking two limits and they converge to some values $0<A,B<\infty$, then the limit of the quotient is the quotient of the limit. You should probably think in epsilon, delta style of convergence to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $A_n \to A$ and $B_n \to B$ with $A \neq 0$ we have $|\frac {B_n} {A_n} -\frac  B A| =\frac {|B_nA-A_n B|} {|A||A_n|}$. This does not exceed $\frac {|B_nA-BA|+|BA-A_n B|} {|A_n||A|}$. Hence $|\frac {B_n} {A_n} -\frac  B A| \leq \frac {|B_n-B||A|+|B||A_n-A|} {(|A|-|A-A_n|)|A|}$ because $|A_n| \geq |A|-|A-A_n|$.  Can you take it from here?